# How to put a span over an image

Tags: html, css

I'd like to put the span element `menu_label` over the image, not at the bottom.

Dunno why it start to get the top and left from the bottom of the container (that is, with class `menu`).

Any ideas?

```css
.menu {width:170px; text-align:center; float:left; background-color:#CCCCCC; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px;}

.menu_label {width:154px; color:#FFFFFF; background-color:#F43B05; float:left; padding:3px; position:relative; top:50px; left:5px;}

.photoStyle{max-width:125px; border:0px; margin:auto;}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
    <img src="http://www.hokiesports.com/radio/images/ilogo.jpg" class="photoStyle" />
    <span class="menu_label">
        This is my span
    </span>                                            
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uc8jc/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Change the position on the `menu_label` to absolute and add `position:relative` to `menu`

http://jsfiddle.net/uc8jc/2/

Comment: Adding `position:relative` to `menu` centers the span more nicely. How does that work?

Comment: when you add position:relative to menu, it makes the span be "absolute" in reference to itself, instead of in reference to the entire page.

Answer (score 4):

Use position: absolute; for the span rather than relative

Comment: Yes but why? The container is static (as default). So the span as relative should take that static in the right way !?!?

Comment: The code you showed had the menu's position set to relative. Because of this the menu is the container of the menu_label. The menu_labels static location is under the image. By using position: absolute; the menu_label's position will be relative to it's container and will disregard other objects in the container.

Note: When setting an objects position to absolute, it's position will be relative to the first parent container that's position is not static.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you’re confused about how `position: relative` works.

You’ve got:

```
position:relative; top:50px; left:5px;
```

That positions the top of the span 50 pixels below where it would have been if positioned statically, and its left edge 5 pixels to the right of where it would have been.

Answer (score 2):

Use `position:absolute` instead of `position:relative`

This reference might help: [CSS Positioning 101](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-positioning-101/)

Answer (score 0):

Add `position:relative` to the container and `position: absolute` to the .men_label.

Here is the code:

```
.menu{
 position:relative;
}
.menu_label {
 position: absolute;
 top: 85%;
 left: 5%;
}
```